# Reference request: Volume 2 of Abhyankar's lectures on algebra?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, linear-algebra, galois-theory

Abhyankar has a magnificent, if meandering (check them out if you want to see what I mean), [set of lectures on algebra](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812773449).

The description:

> This book is a timely survey of much of the algebra developed during the last several centuries including its applications to algebraic geometry and its potential use in geometric modeling.
>
> The present volume makes an ideal textbook for an abstract algebra course, while the forthcoming sequel, Lectures on Algebra II, will serve as a textbook for a linear algebra course. The author's fondness for algebraic geometry shows up in both volumes, and his recent preoccupation with the applications of group theory to the calculation of Galois groups is evident in the second volume which contains more local rings and more algebraic geometry. Both books are based on the author's lectures at Purdue University over the last few years.

Unfortunately I can't find any trace online of the sequel. What ever came of it? Is there a draft lingering around somewhere that can be shared with the world?

**EDIT:** In the remarks by Abhyankar himself at the beginning of the first volume, he says he wrote the lectures and that they were from more recent years, as opposed to the ones mentioned by Carlo in his answer, which were not written down by Abhyankar and were not from more recent years.

Answer (score 1):

This [bibliography](https://books.google.nl/books?id=QHUQBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA12) of Abhyankar lists several unpublished lecture notes on "Algebraic Geometry" that might have formed the basis of this volume 2, which apparently was never published. Purdue University has a videotape of the 1986 and 1987 courses on "Algorithmic Algebraic Geometry I and II" and presumably also has a copy of the lecture notes listed in the bibliography.

Comment: I don't think those notes are drafts of the books, I've edited in an explanation into my original post.